# JavaScript - Checkbox like radiobutton functionality

Tags: javascript, asp.net

How i can code the functionality of checkbox like radiobutton,below is mine quick code but it's seems not so perfect.

```
<asp:checkbox id="chkA" runat="server" onClick="SetCheck(this)"/>
<asp:checkbox id="chkB" runat="server" onClick="SetCheck(this)"/>

<Javascript>
function SetCheck(chk)
{
Switch(chk.id)
{
case "chkA" :
chkB.checked=false;
break;
Case "chkB" :
chkA.checked=false;
break;
}
}
</Javascript>
```

Comment: Did you debug? Look at the ids being passed in. I am willing to bet it is not what you expect. [Also using checkboxes as radio buttons is a bad UX]

Comment: @epascarello : i know chk.id has id with formname like frm1_chkA and case will also like frm1_chkA,But still its quick code & i need suggestion on this.

Comment: @intelliWork if you dont want the ID to change because of forms and masterpages you can set ClientIDMode="Static" for the checkboxes

Comment: @roughnex : thanks for the comment.functionality is working fine but i want to replace my Switch Case block because it's looks like old school code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" id="a" onclick="flip(this)" />
<input type="checkbox" id="b" onclick="flip(this)" />
```

**JavaScript: Flips to other**

```
function flip(cb){
    var other = cb.id==="a" ? "b" : "a";
    document.getElementById(other).checked = !cb.checked;
}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/k9mDx/)

**JavaScript" Allows to be deselected**

```
function flip(cb){
    if (cb.checked) {
        var other = cb.id==="a" ? "b" : "a";
        document.getElementById(other).checked = false;
    }
}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/k9mDx/1/)